# How I can get best arima model in R?

Tags: time-series

I would like to build a time series model for univaraite data in order to predict or forcast. I am a bit new to R but know some of the syntax. More over, I would like to get the best arima model with aicc criteria. I have used arima, auto.arima or sarima. But I could not extract the optimum values f p, d and q. 
I have tried sarima with mapply

```
aicc = mapply(function(i, j) sarima(X1, i, 0, j, no=T)[[3]], rep(0:4, 5), rep(0:4, each=5))
dev.off()
best=which.min(aicc)-1
model =arima(xd, order=c(??, 0, ??)) # I would like to know what will be the order of this model.
```

So that I can use this model for forecast.

Also I have tried sarima with supply like

```
aicc=sapply(0:5, function(i) sarima(X1, i, 0, 0)[[3]])
best=which.min(aicc)-1
m=arima(xd, order=c(best, 0, 0))
```

But here i can not get q compomnent. 
Is there any way to get optimum value of p and q.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `auto.arima` from `forecast` package - it will automatically find the "best" model using more efficient method than proposed by you.

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage,max.p = 5,max.q = 5,max.P = 5,max.Q = 5,max.d = 3,seasonal = TRUE,ic = 'aicc')
plot(forecast(fit,h=20))
str(fit)
```

In this case optimal model is $ARIMA(1,1,1)$ and $aicc=510.8778$. This is the result:
[image]

Comment: +1. You can get the AR and MA orders through `summary(fit)` or `coefficients(fit)`.

Comment: or simply use str(fit) to see all parameters.

Comment: But I do not want seasonal. It is just non seasonal time series.  So how I can get without seasonal then

Comment: if you use seasonal=FALSE then you get the right answer!

Comment: In my case, it gives ARIMA(0,1,2) with drift. But I do  not know much about drift. I am sure I do not want this and I wan more towards p component rather than q. Is it possible?    my data is like this  [1] 0.316090 0.307530 0.290590 0.274100 0.251260 0.246170 0.253220 0.259450
 [9] 0.255040 0.222030 0.208960 0.226830 0.217210 0.188840 0.160510 0.170030
[17] 0.179540 0.159960 0.162150 0.159250 0.139600 0.129890 0.114720 0.108620
[25] 0.104060 0.110100 0.093821 0.079752 0.077417 0.081177 0.074980 0.076597
[33] 0.085255 0.072477 0.072308 0.061657 0.052408 0.044569 0.042093 0.041494
[41] 0.047673

Comment: maybe you need to set max.d = 0

Comment: but this gives ARIMA(1,0,1) with zero mean  . What does it mean? Thanks for helping me

Comment: auto.arima has extensive documentation, did you read  it ? if you want to turn off a specific feature, it can be easily done within the function